# Entity Framework Core removes reference object

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have this post model

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Channel Channel { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int CountViewers { get; set; } 
    public List<ApplicationUser> WhoLiked { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

User

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    [ProtectedPersonalData]      
    [MaxLength(70)]
    [MinLength(3)]
    [Required]
    public override string UserName { get; set; }
    [ProtectedPersonalData]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Required]
    public override string Email { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(70)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(70)]
    [ProtectedPersonalData]
    public string LastName { get; set; }    
}
```

When I add user to "Wholiked" list in some post EF removes this user from others lists (in others posts).
What I am doing wrong?

```
   post.WhoLiked.Add(user);
   _db.Posts.Update(post);
   await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: `What I am doing wrong?` ← I am not sure how you expect anyone that does not have direct access to your code to answer this. Please review [ask] and also provide an [mcve].

Comment: What is `post`, where does it come from and what does it contain? what is `Update`? This is not a standard EF 6.x method. What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Comment: In addition, you have 2 references to ApplicationUser (Wholiked & Author). That requires special configuration. Show the model/fluent code.